# Proof that $f(t) =\lambda(E\cap(−\infty,t])$ is a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

**The problem**

I wish to show that $f(t) =\lambda(E\cap(−\infty,t])$ is a continuous function. 
Where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $E$ is measurable

**My approach**

$f(t) = \lambda(E\cap(−\infty,t]) = \int \chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t]} d\lambda$

Take any $\{t_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that $t_n \to t$ as $n\to\infty$ then as $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t_n]} =  \chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t]}$ almost everywhere and as $\chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t_n]} \leq \chi_{E}$ we have by dominated convergence theorem that (if $\lambda(E) < \infty)$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \int \chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t_n]} d\lambda = \int \lim_{n\to \infty}\chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t_n]} d\lambda = \int \chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t]}d\lambda =f(t) $

**The issue**

However this only works if $E$ is of finite measure. I was wondering if someone had any pointers to extend this to if $E$ had infinite measure.

**Going forwards**

If $f(t) = \infty$ for some $t$ then it is $\infty$ for all $t$  as $f$ is increasing and $f(t-x) \geq f(t) -x $ from subattativity (consider $f(t) = \lambda(E\cap(\infty,t] =   \lambda(E\cap(\infty,t-x] \cup E\cap(t-x,t] \leq \lambda( E\cap(\infty,t-x]) + \lambda(E\cap(t-x,t]) \leq \lambda( E\cap(\infty,t-x]) + \lambda((t-x,t]) = \lambda( E\cap(\infty,t-x]) + x = f(t-x) +x $)

Hence $f(t+x) $ and $f(t-x) + x$ are greater than $f(t) $ so if $f(t)$ is ever infinite then all values are infinite. And it is continuous in its own sort of wierd way

So now consider the case where $E$ has infinite measure and $f(t) < \infty$ then $f(t_n)$ and $f(t)$ are eventually bounded? I think?

I am looking for a way to steam-line the case where $E$ is of infinite measure, any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have shown that $f$ is either infinity everywhere, or finite everywhere.

In the latter case, we don't need that $E$ has finite measure to apply your "dominated convergence" approach: Given a sequence $(t_n)$ such that $t_n \to t$, we can set $\bar{t}=\sup_n t_n$ and just use $\chi_{E\cap(-\infty,\bar{t}]}$ instead of $\chi_E$ as the dominating function (it is integrable because $\mu(E\cap(-\infty,\bar{t}]) = f(\bar{t}) < \infty$):
$$\chi_{E\cap(−\infty,t_n]} \leq \chi_{E\cap(-\infty,\bar{t}]}$$

---

Using the dominated convergence theorem actually seems a bit like overkill here, since you have also shown that $f(t-x) \geq f(t) -x \iff f(t) - f(t-x) \leq x$. That would be already sufficient because it means that
$$f(t)-f(s) \leq t-s \quad\text{for } s<t$$
So $f$ is even Lipschitz-continuous!

Comment: Wow! This was just super thank youuuuu

Comment: Imma comment again because this was actually so good I have my exam tomorow and this has helped me out so much